# SVG not rendering on jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

I was trying to create pdf using jspdf and which is working good except svg.All svg included in the html is not showing.

```
  $(function(){
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
   $("#cmd").click(function() { 
   pdf.addHTML($('.chart'), function() {
    pdf.save('web.pdf');
   });
  });
})
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?